# I'm stumped - Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Tags: php

I'm currently learning php and this has stumped me :(

I would be very grateful if someone could explain what it means and possible solution.

Love to you all!

```
// Get post category info
$category = get_the_category();

if(!empty($category)) {

    // Get last category post is in
    $last_category = end(array_values($category));


    // Get parent any categories and create array
    $get_cat_parents = rtrim(get_category_parents($last_category->term_id, true, ','),',');
    $cat_parents = explode(',',$get_cat_parents);

    // Loop through parent categories and store in variable $cat_display
    $cat_display = '';
    foreach($cat_parents as $parents) {
        $cat_display .= '<li>'.$parents.'</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The `end()` function is pass by reference, and requires an actual variable to pass in as an argument, not the result of an expression: Change `$last_category = end(array_values($category));` to `$categoryValues = array_values($category); $last_category = end($categoryValues);`

Comment: Thank you Mark :) this makes sense and your solution works. I really am thankful <3

Comment: This is so unfair, I got marked down and now I can't post another question as a new member with now bad history. So much for my tutor pointing me here stating it was a good helpful forum. At least Mark and Justinas could offer some help.

Answer (score 1):

`$last_category = end(array_values($category));` will throw error because `end` accepts reference:

```
$vals = array_values($category);
$last_category = end($vals);
```

But I don't think that you need `array_values` of array. It will convert associated array to indexed array.

Comment: Thanks Justinas for taking the time to respond, I'm going to look in to your last paragraph. Many thanks :)